# database error while fetching value from table

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Hi I am using ajax for fetching values from database. My connection with database is ok, but while I am trying to show the result it's showing me an error. How can I solve this? TIA

my config file:

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'steptwor_sscamera');
define('DB_USERNAME','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','');
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if( mysqli_connect_error()) echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
```

ajax.php :

```
<?php

require_once 'config.php';
if(!empty($_POST['type'])){
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $name = $_POST['name_startsWith'];
    $query = "SELECT category_name, product_name, amount FROM v_product_list UPPER($type) LIKE '".strtoupper($name)."%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $name = $row['category_name'].'|'.$row['product_name'].'|'.$row['amount'];
        array_push($data, $name);
    }   
    echo json_encode($data);exit;
}
```

error:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in <b>F
:\xampp\htdocs\sscamera\ajax.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />
[]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysqli\_fetch\_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli\_result, boolean given in .. Then my line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813076/warning-mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-result-boolean-g)

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource (or mysqli\_result), boolean given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole)

Answer (score -1):

You've missed WHERE:

```
    $query = "SELECT category_name, product_name, amount FROM v_product_list WHERE UPPER($type) LIKE '".strtoupper($name)."%'";
```